# Which Polymer Datepicker

Tags: polymer, web-component

I don't see an official Polymer Datepicker component. A quick web search yields the following third party components. One of the below thread has some interesting tidbits. Can we expect an official one in the coming weeks?

- [Polymer Date Picker](https://github.com/christopheclc/polymer-date-picker)
- [this thread](https://github.com/Polymer/paper-elements/issues/20) hints at a material design date picker
- and [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/IJ35qtWzlxc) also shows several date pickers

  - [Calendar Datepicker](https://github.com/Syncofy/calendar-date-picker)
  - [Polymer Datetime Picker](http://shmay.github.io/polymer-datetime-picker/)
  - [Paper Datepicker](https://github.com/HackITtoday/paper-datepicker)
  - [Paper Calendar](https://github.com/Wenqer/paper-calendar/)

Answer (score 10):

I've created [paper-date-picker](https://github.com/bendavis78/paper-date-picker/) ([docs](http://bendavis78.github.io/paper-date-picker/paper-date-picker/index.html) / [demo](http://bendavis78.github.io/paper-date-picker/paper-date-picker/demo/)) and [paper-time-picker](https://github.com/bendavis78/paper-time-picker/)  ([docs](http://bendavis78.github.io/paper-time-picker/paper-time-picker/index.html) / [demo](http://bendavis78.github.io/paper-time-picker/paper-time-picker/demo/))  components with the goal to mirror the android versions as closely as possible, while still having decent performance on mobile devices. I opted against infinite scroll for the date picker, as I couldn't seem to find a way to make it work without sacrificing performance.

Please test on your own devices and let me know what you think (pull requests welcomed)!

Comment: this is a really nice looking (and working) set of date/time pickers.  i would love to use these in my polymer projects.  just need 1.0!  -- maybe someone can fork these repos and migrate them for us?

Comment: I'm working on a 1.0 branch right now, though it's taking longer than I had hoped. 1.0 is a huge change from 0.5, unfortunately.

Comment: @BenDavis could you leave a comment to let us know when its read?

Comment: @Sylar [paper-date-picker](https://github.com/bendavis78/paper-date-picker/) and [paper-time-picker](https://github.com/bendavis78/paper-time-picker/) are both now released for 1.0.

Comment: @BenDavis I have imported the element and added `<paper-date-picker date="2014-04-20"></paper-date-picker>` but its not showing. Where to ask for help?

Comment: @Sylar, let's continue the discussion [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83690/paper-date-picker-discussion).

Comment: @BenDavis both demo links are dead FYI.

Answer (score 5):

**For Polymer 0.5:**

I found this date-picker:

https://github.com/David-Mulder/paper-date-picker

http://david-mulder.github.io/polymer-docs/bower_components/paper-date-picker/

Doesn't use 3rd party libs.

Has good APIs(beside documented ones) as: 
refreshScrollPosition, currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay,...

Example: [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/DUX2IkTLB4LHM8YIT599?p=preview)

Tip:
[Polymer, how to pass value to paper-date-picker attribute that expects string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325014/polymer-how-to-pass-value-to-the-attribute-that-expects-string)

```
 domReady: function(){
    //paper-date-picker expects 'date' attribute to be of type DATE.
    this.birthdate_date = new Date(this.birthdate);
  },
```

Edit:

Time-picker links:

http://nemento.github.io/nemento-timepicker/components/nemento-timepicker/

http://component.kitchen/components/virtual-dev/md-timepicker

Comment: awesome :) do you know any time picker a la material design?

Comment: I have added some links to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Also check out  https://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-date-picker

It has material design inspired styles, so it fits in well with other paper elements. Well documented and apache 2 licensed.