# Polymer, how to pass value to paper-date-picker attribute that expects string?

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to use [paper-date-picker](http://david-mulder.github.io/polymer-docs/bower_components/paper-date-picker/) inside my element. 
How to pass value to paper-date-picker's  'date' attribute?

```
<!-- This is working: -->
<paper-date-picker date="2000/1/21"></paper-date-picker>


 <!-- This is NOT working: 
 Inside <my-birthdate birthdate="1977/1/2"></my-birthdate> -->
<paper-date-picker date='{{birthdate}}'></paper-date-picker>
```

Here is the [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/DUX2IkTLB4LHM8YIT599?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the source for the date-picker, it doesn't handle text very well. Basically, you have to add an observer that converts the value into a date. Also, remove the birthdate from the picker. Here's a quick example...

```
<polymer-element name="my-birthdate" attributes="birthdate">
    <template>
        birthdate = {{birthdate}}
        <paper-date-picker id="picker"></paper-date-picker>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer("my-birthdate", {
            birthdateChanged: function (oldValue, newValue) {
                if (newValue)
                    this.$.picker.date = new Date(newValue);
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Keep in mind, I am not error checking the new value... you'll have to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Values in attributes are always strings. If you want Polymer to convert an attribute string to another type, you have to hint the type you want.

`<my-birthdate birthdate="1977/1/2"></my-birthdate>`

We want `birthdate` to be a `Date`. If we change the definition like so:

```
<script>
  Polymer({
    birthdate: new Date()
  });
</script>
```

then Polymer knows to convert `1977/1/2` into a `Date` object.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ftbtl0eCrklAuIbxKRiP?p=preview

Keep in mind that the binding here is different from above:

`<paper-date-picker date='{{birthdate}}'></paper-date-picker>`

In this case we are asking Polymer to bind `paper-date-picker.date` **property** directly to the `birthdate` **property**. We **do not go through attributes**, because then we would have to convert to string and back and it's dramatically slower.

There is no support in `paper-date-picker` to make a `Date` out of a `String` value in `birthdate`. Therefore, when working with `paper-date-picker` directly (not via attributes) `birthdate` must be `Date` valued.